# Jquery: class name multi ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jquery, foreach

Please Help me to do this

first i have this div

```
<div class="loader" alt="stat.php">
         Here i want to load static
</div>

<div class="loader" alt="notify.php">
         Here i want to load notification
</div>

<div class="loader" alt="alert.php">
        Here i want to load new messages
</div>
```

and i want to do this

i want to make this divs with this class = loader

load every 1 min and get from its alt

mean

after 1 minute  i want to make foreach div

> class="loader"

ajax request to its alt page
 and inside it

mean every 1 minute  i want every div to be like this

```
<div class="loader" alt="stat.php">
         Static loaded from stat.php
</div>

<div class="loader" alt="notify.php">
        notification loaded from notify.php
</div>

<div class="loader" alt="alert.php">
        messages loaded from alert.php
</div>
```

and every 1 minute do this request ???

How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
function refreshDivs() {
    $('.loader').each(function() {
         $this = $(this);
         $this.load($this.prop('alt')); // load in the URL using the alt attribute
    }
}

setInterval(refreshDivs, 60000);  // run every minute
```

Using the each method to process each DOM element with the class `loader` it then uses the load() method to replace the contents of the element with the HTML loaded from the URL.

[Docs on load() here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [docs on each() here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.loader').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('alt');
    var thisDiv = $(this);
    window.setInterval(function () {
        thisDiv.load(url);
    }, 60000);
});
```